# How to release database connections in Pentaho BI server??

Tags: jdbc, datasource, pentaho, mondrian

I am using Pentaho-BI server installation in my web application as a third party installation.I am using its saiku analytics and reporting files by embedding their specific links in iframe of my application. Problem is I am not getting how it creates database connections, in terms of numbers?? Because many times it throws error regarding 'No connection is available in pool'. I know there are properties like max available connection, max idle connections , wait and sql validation. But How to release connections?? And if Pentaho handles it in its own way then how?? Because increasing number of max connections available will create load on database server, when many users are using my BI server.

One solution I found is just to restart my BI server, but It's not a valid solution for production environment. Other solution I think is scheduler, but I have no clues about it and not getting proper info on net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defaults for max connections are incredibly low. This is standard tomcat connection pooling stuff, I would definitely try increasing the default, see if that helps.  you can monitor concurrent connections on the db side - just because you have 100 connections to the db it doesn't necessarily mean they'll be all used at once.

Also; Are you using mysql? You should try the c3po pooling driver it handles timeouts and things better than the standard driver so you shouldnt ever get dead connections sitting in the pool.

Comment: I have seached about c3po pooing driver, It works well with MySQL. Refer http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Configuring+for+MySQL


But Is there any way to do it Using Postgres? this configuration doesn't work in postgresql.hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Hmm I've never come across this issue with dead connections with Postgres.  Usually works fine. Have you increased max connections?

Comment: Hmm...By increasing number of maximum connections, It is working fine, but sometimes I get 'running query...' for long time on my interface. May be some other issue regarding idle connections or MDX queries as It is not giving any backend exception each time.

Comment: yeah so you just need more connections to handle that number of users. As I said before more connections isnt necessarily bad, the defaults are atrociously low anyway. Glad its working!